# Android R file not building when declare-styleable of type enum is added

Tags: android, enums

Recently my Android workspace isn't compiling correctly anymore (the R file isn't created).
After trying the usual like cleaning i started searching deeper.
I discovered that when i comment out the items int my attrs.xml file of the type declare-styleable with the format="enum" the R file is build but not when they are present (not commented out).
Is there a recent change or something with the way you have the declare enums or something?
Here a piece of the project

working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<declare-styleable name="SwipeListView">
    <attr name="swipeOpenOnLongPress" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="swipeAnimationTime" format="integer" />
    <attr name="swipeOffsetLeft" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="swipeOffsetRight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="swipeFrontView" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeBackView" format="reference" />
<!--         <attr name="swipeMode" format="enum"> -->
<!--             <enum name="none" value="0" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="both" value="1" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="right" value="2" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="left" value="3" /> -->
<!--         </attr> -->
<!--         <attr name="swipeActionLeft" format="enum"> -->
<!--             <enum name="reveal" value="0" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="dismiss" value="1" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="choice" value="2" /> -->
<!--         </attr> -->
<!--         <attr name="swipeActionRight" format="enum"> -->
<!--             <enum name="reveal" value="0" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="dismiss" value="1" /> -->
<!--             <enum name="choice" value="2" /> -->
<!--         </attr> -->
<!--         <attr name="swipeDrawableChecked" format="reference" /> -->
<!--         <attr name="swipeDrawableUnchecked" format="reference" /> -->
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<declare-styleable name="SwipeListView">
    <attr name="swipeOpenOnLongPress" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="swipeAnimationTime" format="integer" />
    <attr name="swipeOffsetLeft" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="swipeOffsetRight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="swipeFrontView" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeBackView" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeMode" format="enum">
        <enum name="none" value="0" />
        <enum name="both" value="1" />
        <enum name="right" value="2" />
        <enum name="left" value="3" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="swipeActionLeft" format="enum">
        <enum name="reveal" value="0" />
        <enum name="dismiss" value="1" />
        <enum name="choice" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="swipeActionRight" format="enum">
        <enum name="reveal" value="0" />
        <enum name="dismiss" value="1" />
        <enum name="choice" value="2" />
    </attr>
    <attr name="swipeDrawableChecked" format="reference" />
    <attr name="swipeDrawableUnchecked" format="reference" />

</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: The R tag is not for R files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining the enum outside the declare styleable and then using attr without any format in the declare-styleable

Comment: Nope didn't do it... some how my entire eclipse isn't accepting enums in xml anymore. I replaced the enums now temporarily with integer values and that does work but is of course not the real solution but a lame workaround...